# How to return data from a subscribed method using EventAggregator and Microsoft Prism libraries

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, prism, eventaggregator

I am working on a WPF project, using MVVM and `Microsoft Prism libraries`. So, when I need to communicate through classes I use the class `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Events.MefEventAggregator` and I publish events and subscribe methods as below:

To publish:

`myEventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Publish(myParams)`

To Subscribe:

`myEventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Subscribe(MySubscribedMethod)`

But my question is: **Is there a way to return some data from the "Subscribed method" after publishing an event??**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I know, if all the event subscribers are using the `ThreadOption.PublisherThread` option (which is also the default), the event is performed synchronously and the subscribers can modify the `EventArgs` object, so you could have in the publisher

```cs
myEventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Publish(myParams)
if (myParams.MyProperty)
{
   // Do something
}
```

The subscriber code would look like this:

```cs
// Either of these is fine.
myEventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Subscribe(MySubscribedMethod)
myEventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Subscribe(MySubscribedMethod, ThreadOption.PublisherThread)

private void MySubscribedMethod(MyEventArgs e)
{
    // Modify event args
    e.MyProperty = true;
}
```

If you know that the event should always be called synchronously, you can create your own base class for events (instead of `CompositePresentationEvent<T>`) which overrides the `Subscribe` method, and only allow subscribers to use the `ThreadOption.PublisherThread` option. It would look something like this:

```cs
public class SynchronousEvent<TPayload> : CompositePresentationEvent<TPayload>
{
    public override SubscriptionToken Subscribe(Action<TPayload> action, ThreadOption threadOption, bool keepSubscriberReferenceAlive, Predicate<TPayload> filter)
    {
        // Don't allow subscribers to use any option other than the PublisherThread option.
        if (threadOption != ThreadOption.PublisherThread)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        // Perform the subscription.
        return base.Subscribe(action, threadOption, keepSubscriberReferenceAlive, filter);
    }
}
```

then instead of deriving `MyEvent` from `CompositePresentationEvent`, you derive it from `SynchronousEvent`, which will guarantee you that the event will be called synchronously and that you will get the modified `EventArgs`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I could understand your point, I return the data through the EventArgs and It works. Just for the record, I wasn't able to create the `SyncronousEvent` class since the method `SubscriptionToken` is not `virtual`. Howerver your question was very helpful to me.

Comment: @Dante You are not overriding `SubscriptionToken`, but the `Subscribe` method (which is virtual).

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was talking about the method `Subscribe` which is not virtual, I am looking at it right now and if I try to compile your example VS2010 tells me that the method is not `virtual`. Anyway, your solution is what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: @Dante The specific overload I used in my code wasn't overridable. I've modified my answer to use the correct overload, which is definitely virtual :)

Comment: Prism 6 changed `CompositePresentationEvent` to `PubSubEvent`  https://stackoverflow.com/q/34668759/2122718