# Migrate Prism 4 to Prism 6 - CompositePresentationEvent

Tags: prism-6

I want to migrate a project written with Prism 4 into Prism 6.

In Prism 4 the `CompositePresentationEvent<T>` type is under `Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Events` namespace.

But when I pulled Prism 6 from nugget and removed old Prism 4 references, I could not see this event type anywhere in Prism 6 namespaces.

Anyone can help me a bit?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `CompositePresentationEvent` has been removed in Prism 6. If I recall correctly, if was deprecated in Prism 5, and removed completely in Prism 6.

Now, you need to use the `PubSubEvent<TPayload>` in the `Prism.Events` namespace.

Answer (score 5):

What R. Richards wrote is correct and has thus been correctly marked as an answer.
Might I however offer you the following link as a reference:

[Upgrading from Prism Library 4.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921144(v=pandp.40).aspx)

As the title suggests it refers to upgrading from version 4.1 to 5.0 but there are, apart from the change mentioned here, other changes noted there which you might find helpful.